# TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

```
n_inc = torch.tensor(1)
theta = torch.tensor(0.6109)
phi = torch.tensor(0)
k0 = torch.tensor(6.2832)


kinc = k0*n_inc*[torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi),
                 torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), 
                 torch.cos(theta)]
print(kinc)
```

when I am running the code, it is showing the following error message-

> TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted
> to an index

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thanks to @Hamza for pointing out the mistake. The code is working using `Numpy`. Haven't found any direct way to do it with `PyTorch`.

'''

```
import numpy as np
import torch

theta = 0.6109
phi = 0.0
k0 = 6.2832
n_inc = 1.0

kinc = k0*n_inc*np.array([np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi), 
                          np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), 
                          np.cos(theta)])
kinc = torch.tensor(kinc)
print(kinc)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know that when you multiply a list with a number, the list is duplicated with times equivalent to this number. This number should be integer, otherwise you will get the error you had:

```
torch.tensor(0.6109)*[torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi), #<--- it throws an error
                 torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), 
                 torch.cos(theta)]
```

If you want to repeat the list, you only need to multiply the list with an integer tensor, not a float tensor.

If you want to multiply the integer tensor by each element in the list. You should only convert the list to NumPy array:

```
kinc = k0*n_inc*np.array([torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi), #<- NumPy array not a list
                 torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), 
                 torch.cos(theta)])
```

You do not need to convert the sin and cos to NumPy type.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was able to do it with NumPy array and then convert the result to a torch tensor. Is there a way to do it directly with PyTorch?

Comment: @galib Your logic is not correct, how do you want to repeat a list with 0.678 times? How did you do it with numpy? I think you should add to your question how you did it with numpy to understand what you are trying to do and be able to change your answer to Pytorch.

Comment: sorry. Maybe you didn't understand it because of my wording. I have added the Numpy code

Answer (score 0):

use

```
torch.stack([np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi),
                 np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), 
                 np.cos(theta)], dim= 0)
```

to directly stack a list of Torch Tensor to a new Torch Tensor.

Answer (score 0):

here you are creating a Python array by the statement 
`[torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi), torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), torch.cos(theta)]`
if you want to perform a multiplication on this you may have to convert the list into a torch tensor

you can do this by 
`torch.tensor([torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi), torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), torch.cos(theta)])`

this will ensure that you don't have to switch your data from GPU to CPU (as in the case of numpy operation)

```
import torch

n_inc = torch.tensor(1)
theta = torch.tensor(0.6109)
phi = torch.tensor(0)
k0 = torch.tensor(6.2832)


kinc = k0*n_inc*torch.tensor([torch.sin(theta)*torch.cos(phi),
                 torch.sin(theta)*torch.sin(phi), 
                 torch.cos(theta)])
print(kinc)
```